# get the seo-unfriendly version of a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, disqus

I'm adding disqus commenting to some articles on our site and all URLs are SEO friendly.
This means that, if the title of the article changes so will the URL of that article, which will discard the previous disqus comments (linked to the previous version of the URL).
The solution would be to strip out the title of the article from the URL before passing it to Disqus.

So I need to turn "http://mydomain.com/article/123-myarticle/section/1-sectiontitle" into "http://mydomain.com/article/123/section/1"

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

*PS: I'm very new to Rails (i'm taking over a developed project)*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extract anything from the URL.
All you need to give to Disqus is a unique id.

So you can add a method to your model, called `disqus_id` for instance:

```
def disqus_id
    "name_of_your_model_#{id}"
end
```

and then, in the javascript:

```
disqus_identifier = "<%= @your_model.disqus_id %>";
```